# How can I make `-[MPMoviePlayerController backgroundView]` to show immediately?

Tags: iphone, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller

Currently my `-[MPMoviePlayerController backgroundView]` does not appear until movie loaded enough. So `UIActivityIndicatorView` which I placed on there does not appear immediately. This drives me crazy. The only solution  have been found is placing duplicated indicator-view somewhere between background-view and `-[MPMoviePlayerController view]`. But this does not look regular, and definitely a view hierarchy hack which is not guaranteed to work properly. If the background-view shows immediately, all will work magically.

How can I make the background-view immediately before movie loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the backgroundView but the view of the moviecontroller itself...

Following steps (assuming your `MPMovieControllerPlayer` instance is called `moviePlayerController` and your `UIActivityIndicatorView` instance is called `activityIndicatorView`)

- Add your UIActivityIndicatorView on top of the MPMoviePlayerController view (e.g. `[moviePlayerController.view addSubview:activityIndixatorView];`)
- Start animating the activity indicator
- Register for `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`
- Within the handler of the above notification, watch out for `moviePlayerController.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable`
- If the above condition is matched, hide your activity indicator

Comment: Unfortunately, `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` notifications are raised too early or too lately, so activity-indicator will be disappeared before video displayed. For slow connections, the time gap is too long. So I couldn't use this way :(

Comment: That is weird... but you may use MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange instead or additionally to MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification for hiding that activity indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but [Can a UIActivityIndicator be displayed over a MPMoviePlayerController in full screen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799299/can-a-uiactivityindicator-be-displayed-over-a-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-full-scr) may help you a bit

Comment: As I mentioned in comment on @Till's answer, the solution couldn't solved the issue...