# How to use a activity indicator before the video starts playing using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I need to play a video in my UIViewcontroller using MPMoviePlayerController. So before playing the video i need to show an activity Indicator View before the video is buffered. Once the video starts playing i need to remove the Activity Indicator. I am not able to find out on how to get notified as soon as the video starts playing. Any suggestion on this would be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your probably looking for something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"VIEW DID LOAD");
    // Register to receive a notification that the movie is now in memory and ready to play
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieLoadStateDidChange:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

}

-(void)movieLoadStateDidChange:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"STATE CHANGED");
    if(MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK ) {
        NSLog(@"State is Playable OK");
        NSLog(@"Enough data has been buffered for playback to continue uninterrupted..");
        aiv.hidden = YES;
        [aiv stopAnimating];
    }

}
```

I also found that from this link which may help you out too: http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=48

Comment: Thanks a lot...its working.. Can u please suggest me an alternative on how to implementing something to display a custom message along with the activity indicator..something like "Please wait while the video loads..."

Comment: Sure, you can add a UILabel in the same places where you create the UIProgressView and then hide it in the same places you hide the UIProgressView.

Comment: As @Pavel suggested, the comparison is wrong. `MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK` is a **bitmask** so it should be compared like `if ( thePlayer.state & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK ) { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 1):

if(MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK ) { - this check is incorect. It's always TRUE.

Take a look:
[Can a UIActivityIndicator be displayed over a MPMoviePlayerController in full screen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799299/can-a-uiactivityindicator-be-displayed-over-a-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-full-sc)